# MinMax element of multiple attributes in an object C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class with floating point attributes and I want to find the minimum and maximum for all of them.

```
class Block {
public:
 Block();

protected:
 float x;
 float y;
 float width;
 float height;
}
```

I could just use a for loop if I desire O(N) behavior.

```
float x_min = __FLT_MAX__, y_min = __FLT_MAX__;
float width_min = __FLT_MAX__, height_min = __FLT_MAX__;
float x_max = __FLT_MIN__, y_max = __FLT_MIN__;
float width_max = __FLT_MIN__, height_max = __FLT_MIN__;

for (const Block& block : m_blocks)  {

    if (block.x < x_min) x_min = block.x;
    else if (block.x > x_max)  x_max = block.x;

    if (block.y < y_min) y_min = block.y;
    else if (block.y > y_max) y_max = block.y;

    if (block.width < width_min) width_min = block.width;
    else if (block.width > width_max) width_max = block.width;

    if (block.height < height_min) height_min = block.height;
    else if (block.height > height_max) height_max = block.height;
}
```

I have used `std::minmax_element` before, for vector of pairs and it is convenient for that use case.

```
std::pair<float, float> positions;
const auto minmax = std::minmax_element(positions.begin(), positions.end());
```

It seems to work only with pairs. Any other elegant alternatives possible?.

By elegant I mean less code size while maintaining performance. I do not want to repeat `std::minmax_element` four times.

This question is just a curiosity. The loop works just fine.

Comment: Look at overload #3 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: You want to find min/max of the attributes of the single `Block` object? Or, you have multiple objects and want to find min/max for each attribute separately?

Comment: "if I desire O(N) behavior" why would it be any other `O(?)`? Also, no matter how you do it, there will be a loop somewhere. What do you call "elegant" ? The question would be more clear if you would show your attempt and explain what you do not like about it

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: "It seems to work only with pairs." what makes you think that? It returns a pair, but the parameters can be almost anything. Did you actually try it?

Comment: btw your loop is wrong. On the first iteration the first value will be smaller than the current min and bigger than the current max but you consider only the first

Comment: yes, this is just a representation. I have used similar structures before and they work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems to work only with pairs.

This is not correct.

[`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) works with any forward iterators. Also it takes a comparator that lets you define how to compare the elements. You *could* write:

```
auto minmax_x = std::minmax_element(blocks.begin(),blocks.end(),
                  [](cosnt Block& a, const Block& b) { return a.x < b.x; });
```

However, you would need several calls, ie traversing the container several times, to get min and max for each member.

There is no ready to use algorithm that gets you min and max of all members in one go. You could squeeze it into an algorithm, but unlikely will it be "more elegant" than your loop.

Note however, that your code is wrong:

```
if (block.x < x_min) x_min = block.x;
else if (block.x > x_max)  x_max = block.x;
```

Consider a container with a single element. Then `x_min` and `x_max` should take the value from that single element, but you will only assign `x_min`. You need either:

```
if (block.x < x_min) x_min = block.x;
if (block.x > x_max)  x_max = block.x;
```

..or take the values from the first element as initial values (but then you need extra handling of an empty container).

What is "elegant" is a matter of taste and opinions, though I would probably consider something along the line of:

```
class Block {
public:
 Block();
 void keep_min(const Block& other) {
     if (other.x < x) x = other.x;
     if (other.y < y) y = other.y;
 }
 void keep_max(const Block& other) {
     if (other.x > x) x = other.x;
     if (other.y > y) y = other.y;
 }
protected:
 float x;
 float y;
}
```

so that the loop becomes trivial:

```
if (blocks.size()) {
    Block min = blocks.front();
    Block max = blocks.front();
    for (const auto& block : blocks) {
        min.keep_min(block);
        max.keep_max(block);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most compact solution I can get up with:

```
struct Block
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float width;
    float height;
};

using Field = float (Block::*); // pointer to member
using MinMax = std::pair<float, float>; // (min, max)
                            // x        y      width  height
using MinMaxAll = std::tuple<MinMax, MinMax, MinMax, MinMax>;

MinMax compare(const MinMax& a, const Block& b, Field f)
{ return std::make_pair((a.first < b.*f ? a.first:b.*f), (a.second < b.*f ? b.*f : a.second)); }

MinMaxAll compareall(const vector<Block>& blocks)
{
    assert(!blocks.empty());

    MinMax t = make_pair(numeric_limits<float>::lowest(), numeric_limits<float>::max());
    MinMaxAll mm = make_tuple(t, t, t, t);

    for (const auto& b : blocks)
        mm = make_tuple(
            compare(get<0>(mm), b, &Block::x),
            compare(get<1>(mm), b, &Block::y),
            compare(get<2>(mm), b, &Block::width),
            compare(get<3>(mm), b, &Block::height));

    return mm;
}
```